# Return the indices "ordering" of the list?

Tags: haskell

Is there some Haskell function that can take a list, say of doubles, like this:

```
[0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 0.7]
```

and return a list of integers, which represent indices of the items in order. In the above case it would be:

```
[2, 0, 1, 3]
```

NOTE: What I am trying to achieve is some function (let's call it `consistent`) that can compare two lists of doubles, and tell the user if the lists's relative ordering is consistent:

```
> consistent [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] [2.1 3.5 4.6]
True
> consistent [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] [3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
False
```

Comment: The APL grade up operator.  Oh, that's not Haskell. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip the list with `[0..]` to pair each item with its index. Then you can sort that list and use map to get the second element of every pair (the index).

Comment: They are? consistent [2, 4, 6, 5] [2, 4, 6, 3] is false, but I think the comparison list you are talking about says the are the same? [2,4,6,5] -> [GT, GT, LT] and [2,4,6,3] -> [GT, GT, LT]. I don't think it can be done in linear time.

Comment: @Doug Oops. You're right. My idea does not work - it worked so well with the examples I tried in my head though :-( I removed it from my answer

Comment: Thanks, the zip idea is great... however my consistent function has a really hairy signature... `consistent:: [[Double]] -> Bool`need coffee

Comment: @drozzy Are you saying that (despite what you said in your question), you want the type of `consistent` to be `[[Double]] -> Bool` or that when you follow my advice the type ends up being that even though you do not want that? If the former: I don't see how that's problematic, you can still apply my advice without having to change anything. If the latter: I can't really tell you how that happened without seeing your code other than that you must be doing something wrong when defining `consistent` (apparently not defining it using two arguments).

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask another question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314983/parse-error-on-pattern

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this too:

```
swap (a, b) = (b, a)

consistent a b = sort (zip a b) == map swap $ sort (zip b a)
```

I've never coded seriously in Haskell, so the syntax is just something vaguely similar to what I remember after having read "Learn yourself a Haskell..." months ago.

Comment: I'm not convinced that works.  The order you get sorting `a` is not necessarily the same as the order you get by sorting `zip a b`.  Because when elements are equal in `a` the first keeps the original order (sort is stable), whereas the second uses `b` to determine the order of those elements.

Comment: I think I understand your point, but if that happens that should imply that the ordering in B was not consistent after all, right? In fact, the definition of the "consistent" method varies if the sorting method is stable or not :-/

Comment: @fortran, the problem is only when two unequal (in the purest sense) elements compare equal (according to the `(==)` or `compare` functions).  If elements that compare equal are always indistinguishable, then this implementation is fine.